# Change variable of a spawnable blueprint from another class (Unreal C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

When I pick up my powerup I want it to change a bool variable "isExplosiveBullets" to true so when I shoot the bullets it will have other properties, I believe that the problem is that I am try to access something that is not yet spawned in the game world.

When I try to pick up the powerup then the editor crashes. But I can compile that is why I think that this issue occurs because I do try to access something that does not exist.

I have also tried the "New" keyword but that does not work when I search around the internet I found out that Unreal does not really support the new keyword in the same sens as C++.

Thanks for helping out!

```
cpp: ExplosiveBulletPowerUp

#include "ExplosiveBulletPowerUp.h"
#include "DM/DMProjectile.h"
#include "DM/DMCharacter.h"

// Sets default values
AExplosiveBulletPowerUp::AExplosiveBulletPowerUp()
{
    OnActorBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this,&AExplosiveBulletPowerUp::OnOverlapBegin);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AExplosiveBulletPowerUp::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

void AExplosiveBulletPowerUp::OnOverlapBegin(class AActor* OverlappedActor,class AActor* OtherActor)
{
    if (OtherActor->ActorHasTag("player"))
    {
        ADMProjectile ProjectileClass;
        ProjectileClass.isExplosiveBullets = false;

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Explosvie %s"), ProjectileClass.isExplosiveBullets);
    
        OverlappedActor->Destroy();
    }
}
```

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "DM.generated.h"

UCLASS(config=Game)
class ADMProjectile : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    /** Sphere collision component */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, Category=Projectile)
    class USphereComponent* CollisionComp;

    /** Projectile movement component */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Movement, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UProjectileMovementComponent* ProjectileMovement;

public:
    ADMProjectile();

    /** called when projectile hits something */
    UFUNCTION()
    void OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit);

    /** Returns CollisionComp subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class USphereComponent* GetCollisionComp() const { return CollisionComp; }
    /** Returns ProjectileMovement subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class UProjectileMovementComponent* GetProjectileMovement() const { return ProjectileMovement; }

    // Exposes the variable in the blueprint so it can be edited
    UPROPERTY(Editanywhere)
    float WeaponDamage = 25.0f;

    UPROPERTY(Editanywhere)
    bool isExplosiveBullets;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    TSubclassOf <AActor> ExplosionVFX;
};
```

Comment: Do you want this pickup to make projectiles that were fired before the pickup was gained into explosive? If so, maybe try making `isExplosiveBullets` into a static member variable (which would require using `static bool isExplosiveBullets;` and getting rid of the UPROPERTY declaration, then using `ADMProjectile::isExplosiveBullets = true;`). If not, then maybe you need to change a variable on the player or weapon or whatever does the spawning of the projectiles so it knows to set that `isExplosiveBullets` to true when each projectile is spawned.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks will update you when I have the time to try!